# Have no bibliography result

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, biber

I'm using TeXstudio and trying to list the bibliography content in the document. I compiled the .tex file and there is no errors but I got no output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\newenvironment{subs}
  {\adjustwidth{2em}{0pt}}
  {\endadjustwidth}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}


@article{awad2011machine,
  title={Machine Learning methods for E-mail Classification},
  author={Awad, WA and ELseuofi, SM},
  journal={International Journal of Computer Applications},
  volume={16},
  number={1},
  year={2011},
  publisher={International Journal of Computer Applications, 244 5 th Avenue,\# 1526, New York, NY 10001, USA India}
}

@article{willett2006porter,
  title={The Porter stemming algorithm: then and now},
  author={Willett, Peter},
  journal={Program},
  volume={40},
  number={3},
  pages={219--223},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Emerald Group Publishing Limited}
}



@inproceedings{mccallum1998comparison,
  title={A comparison of event models for naive bayes text classification},
  author={McCallum, Andrew and Nigam, Kamal and others},
  booktitle={AAAI-98 workshop on learning for text categorization},
  volume={752},
  pages={41--48},
  year={1998},
  organization={Citeseer}
}


@article{pop2006approach,
  title={An approach of the Naive Bayes classifier for the document classification},
  author={Pop, Ioan},
  journal={General Mathematics},
  volume={14},
  number={4},
  pages={135--138},
  year={2006},
  publisher={University}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{sample}




\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I tried so many proposed solutions but unfortunately nothing worked

Comment: [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) uses `\addbibresource{sample.bib}`. Try that instead of `\bibliography{sample}`.

Comment: Unfortunatel it didn't work:( @Werner

Comment: Did you compile with BibTeX as well?

Comment: Yes, still no errors but no output @Werner

Comment: I can't replicate your problem then...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Not sure I follow you. The OP's code does feature the instruction `\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing all exclamation marks from your posting. No need to shout, really. We're not deaf.

Comment: If I use `biber` instead of `bibtex`, there is no issue, nor there is with `bibtex` if I add another set of braces like `publisher={{...}}`. On the other hand, the `publisher` field is not used for the `@article` type, so removing it seems to be a good idea.

Comment: @CarLaTeX It should make no difference if one uses `\addbibresource` or `\bibliography` in this case. But note that the file extension is mandatory with `\addbibresource`, so it should be `\addbibresource{sample.bib}`.

Comment: You have tagged your question with Biber, but your code uses `backend=bibtex`, so you have to run BibTeX and not Biber. You should switch to `backend=biber` and run Biber, see [here for help in getting biber to run in your favourite editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Note also that normally, the `publisher` field does not contain the full address of the publisher, there is the `location` field for the city of the publisher. But, as egreg noted, the `publisher` field is ignored for `@article`s anyway.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @samcarter It still haven't solved yet. The last solution I did is to use the online editor but the local editor still has the problem. Thank you

Comment: @F505 Maybe it then would be good to give some feedback to the answer you received?

Answer (score 3):

> I tried so many proposed solutions but unfortunately nothing worked

It would be helpful if you were a bit more specific as to *which* proposed solutions you've tried.

I don't have TeXstudio on my computer, so I can't judge what your front-end is doing. When I run your code from TeXworks as the front-end and MacTeX2016 as the back-end, I do notice that biblatex issues complaints about "too many commas" in the `publisher` field of the entry `awad2011machine`. If I change the field named `publisher` to `xpublisher` in all entries and re-run your code, I get no more warning messages.

That said, you should make more of an effort to make sure that the *contents* of all entries are correct. A quick glance over your code immediately shows incorrect capitalization and failure to prevent lowercasing of words by BibTeX.

Here's the output of applying some judicious corrections to your code -- note that I've also replaced `\bibliography{sample}` with the more idiomatic `\addbibresource{sample.bib}`:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{awad2011machine,
  title  ={Machine learning methods for \mbox{E-mail} Classification},
  author ={Awad, W. A. and Elseuofi, S. M.},
  journal={International Journal of Computer Applications},
  volume ={16},
  number ={1},
  year   ={2011},
  xpublisher={International Journal of Computer Applications, 244 5th Avenue, \#~1526, New York, NY 10001, USA}
}
@article{willett2006porter,
  title  ={The {Porter} stemming algorithm: then and now},
  author ={Willett, Peter},
  journal={Program},
  volume ={40},
  number ={3},
  pages  ={219--223},
  year   ={2006},
  xpublisher={Emerald Group Publishing Limited}
}
@inproceedings{mccallum1998comparison,
  title  ={A comparison of event models for {Naive Bayes} text classification},
  author ={McCallum, Andrew and Nigam, Kamal and others},
  booktitle={AAAI-98 Workshop on Learning for Text Categorization},
  volume ={752},
  pages  ={41--48},
  year   ={1998},
  organization={Citeseer}
}
@article{pop2006approach,
  title  ={An approach of the {Naive Bayes} classifier for the document classification},
  author ={Pop, Ioan},
  journal={General Mathematics},
  volume ={14},
  number ={4},
  pages  ={135--138},
  year   ={2006},
  xpublisher={University}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{changepage}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\newenvironment{subs}
%  {\adjustwidth{2em}{0pt}}
%  {\endadjustwidth}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```